# Why is there an 'unpaid standing order' on my bank statement when I have plenty of cleared funds?

Tags: united-kingdom, banking

Recently a Standing Order from my account has started appearing on my bank statement as an 'Unpaid Standing Order'. The money goes out of the account, but is then returned. I have sufficient cleared funds, so that isn't the problem. What is going on? What action should I take?

Comment: Have you spoken to your bank about this? If so then what did they say?

Comment: I've just checked with the bank, and the payment is being returned by the other account. I'm now investigating why that would be... I will update with an Answer if I can solve this mystery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The destination Bank Account was closed.

In this case I contacted my own bank and asked what was happening with this regular payment. It was being returned by the destination bank.

I contacted the organization that I was trying to pay - they had moved to a different bank with new account details. I set up a new payment to resume paying this organization.